# How to express "you are unavailable" for few days

Tags: sentence-construction, american-english, email

When you are going on a holiday and want to update your students - 
Is this a correct English to message -

> **Just a Note :**
>  I won't be available for next 2 days

Is there any better/eloquent way to write the same. 
The message includes the `Just a Note` part.

Comment: Put actual dates. If you wrote it on Monday and I read it on Tuesday, I’ll think you won’t be back until Friday.

Answer (score 2):

Looks mostly fine to me.  I might have expressed it with different words, but yours is clear, concise and understandable.

I would have included  "*the* next two days".  And I'd have included more preamble, and the afterword:

> Dear all,
>
> I hope you're making good progress on your essays.
>
> Just to let you know, I won't be available for the next two days
>
> I'll be checking emails on Monday, till then,
>
> {signoff}

Actually, I'd probably have written more, but I tend to be long-winded in emails.

Comment: And for normal emails. When you are talking about some other stuff. Is it appropriate to write a `PS:` type thing at the bottom of email and mention I will be unavailable during next 2 days .. ?

Comment: You can do, but I don't.  The PS is from pen-and-paper letters, when you have an Idea after you have signed the letter.  In an email you can just go and edit the email. So PS is redundant, except for having a particular effect.

Comment: I can't edit one character, and it's ESL, so it's important: Can you remove the apostrophe from "your's".